# recursive query with peer relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

Let's say there is a table of relationships
(entity_id, relationship, related_id)

```
1, A, 2     
1, A, 3      
3, B, 5 
1, C, null 
12, C, 1 
100, C, null
```

I need a query that will pull all related rows.
For example, if i queried for entity_id = 1, the following rows should be pulled

```
1, A, 2     
1, A, 3      
3, B, 5 
1, C, null 
12, C, 1
```

Actually, if i queried for entity_id = 1, 2, 3, 5, or 12, the resultset should be the same.

This is different than the standard manager-employee paradigm as there is no hierarchy.  The relationships can go in any direction.

---

**EDIT**
None of the answers posted thus far worked.

I was able to come up with a solution that works.

I'll give the solution credit to the one who can clean this monstrosity into something more elegant.

```
with tab as ( 
-- union for reversals
 select id, entity_id, r.related_id, 1 level
 , cast('/' + cast(entity_id as varchar(1000)) + '/'  as varchar(1000)) path 
  from _entity_relation r 
  where not exists(select null from _entity_relation r2 where r2.related_id=r.entity_id) 
    or r.related_id is null 
 union
 select id, related_id, r.entity_id, 1 level
 , cast('/' + cast(related_id as varchar(1000)) + '/' as varchar(1000)) path 
  from _entity_relation r 
  where not exists(select null from _entity_relation r2 where r2.related_id=r.entity_id) 
    or r.related_id is null 

-- create recursive path
union all 
 select r.id, r.entity_id, r.related_id, tab.level+1
 , cast(tab.path + '/' + cast(r.entity_id as varchar(100)) + '/' + '/' + cast(r.related_id as varchar(1000)) + '/' as varchar(1000)) path 
  from _entity_relation r 
  join tab 
  on tab.related_id = r.entity_id   
) 

select x.id
    , x.entity_id
    ,pr.description as relation_description
    ,pt.first_name + coalesce(' ' + pt.middle_name,'') + ' ' + pt.last_name as relation_name
    ,CONVERT(CHAR(10), pt.birth_date, 101) as relation_birth_date   
from (

select entity_id, MAX(id) as id from (
select distinct tab.id, entity_id
from tab 
join( 
    select path 
    from tab  
    where entity_id=@in_entity_id
) p on p.path like tab.path + '%' or tab.path like p.path + '%'
union
select distinct tab.id, related_id
from tab 
join( 
    select path 
    from tab  
    where entity_id=@in_entity_id
) p on p.path like tab.path + '%' or tab.path like p.path + '%'
union
select distinct tab.id, entity_id
from tab 
join( 
    select path 
    from tab  
    where related_id=@in_entity_id
) p on p.path like tab.path + '%' or tab.path like p.path + '%'
union
select distinct tab.id, related_id
from tab 
join( 
    select path 
    from tab  
    where related_id=@in_entity_id
) p on p.path like tab.path + '%' or tab.path like p.path + '%'
) y
group by entity_id
) x
join _entity_relation pr on pr.id = x.id
join _entity pt on pt.id = x.entity_id
where x.entity_id <> @in_entity_id;
```

Comment: If you'd query for `entity_id = 1` shouldn't all your records start with **1** so only first, second and fourth record should be returned? .. ok I get it... You want recursion to then go through `reated_id` and include those rows as well... But How did you get to return **12,C,1**? Recursion can't get there, because it's turned around...

Comment: it's a peer relationship - the relationship can go in either direction

Comment: Can there be cyclic relationships? Is it allowed to add `5, D, 1` building the relation path of `3 - 5 - 1 - 3 - 5 ` etc.

Comment: yes - that is the thing that makes it tricky...

Answer (score 1):

### Solution using two CTEs

I first created a table with relationships that go both ways and then created a recursive CTE that uses this both ways results to build whole hierarchies with ancestor paths...

```
with both as
(
    select *, 0 as rev
    from t
    where related_id is not null

    union

    select *, 1
    from t
),
recurs as
(
    select *, cast('/' as varchar(100)) as anc
    from both
    where entity_id is null

    union all

    select b.*, cast(re.anc + cast(b.entity_id as varchar) + '/' as varchar(100))
    from both b
        join recurs re
        on (re.related_id = b.entity_id)
    where charindex('/'+cast(isnull(b.entity_id,'') as varchar)+'/', re.anc) = 0
)
select *
/*
    THIS ONE SHOULD BE USED TO RETURN TO ORIGINAL
    case when is_reverse = 1 then related_id else entity_id end as entity_id,
    relationship,
    case when is_reverse = 0 then related_id else entity_id end as related_id
*/
from recurs
where related_id = xXx or
      charindex('/'+cast(xXx as varchar)+'/', anc) != 0
```

Replace `xXx` with actual value.

This query assumes that root element is the one with `entity_id = null`, so it builds the whole recursion from there. If that's not the case you'll have to change it accordingly.

I've added loop checks either loops are 1,2,3,4,5,**1** or 1,2,3,4,5,**3**... So total or partial loops. Both will work.

Comment: @mson: I've heavily edited my query. I've created a table with your data and tested it. Recursion avoids relationship loops and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: thank you so much for your efforts - I'm testing it out right now

Comment: @mson: could you be a bit more specific about what didn't work? Because first of all based on your data, results were fine and second of all I created this query based on my understanding of the problem taht may not be identical to yours. But I'm sure you can use my query as a starting point to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful with you data as to accomplish your task you must avoid circular references. The following query can be optimized but for sure it'll work

```
;with tab as (
 select entity_id, relationship, related_id, 1 level, cast('/' + cast(entity_id as varchar(1000)) as varchar(1000)) path
  from #r r
  where not exists(select null from #r r2 where r2.related_id=r.entity_id)
    or r.related_id is null
union all
 select r.entity_id, r.relationship, r.related_id, tab.level+1, cast(tab.path + '/' + cast(r.entity_id as varchar(100)) as varchar(1000)) path
  from #r r
  join tab
  on tab.related_id = r.entity_id  
)
select distinct tab.* 
    from tab
    join(
select path
    from tab 
    where entity_id=1) p
    on p.path like tab.path + '%' or tab.path like p.path + '%'
```

Comment: The query result includes the unwanted record 100, c, null in the final result

Comment: I've tested the query. The result didn't include unwanted records and worked perfect.